# C# class libary show and update a form on seperate thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, dll

I am creating a dll in C# with a public method that should be called from a different program. When that program calls this method: 'ShowMsg', it should create and show a small form (basically an alert popup) with a certain message in a certain color based on the type of message.
The form should remain visible until the calling program calls ShowMsg again with different parameters, upon which the same form should update it's message and color.

What I now have in the calling program is this:

```
//Create the form here but do not show it yet
AlertMsg alertMsg = new AlertMsg();

//Show the form with this message
alertMsg.ShowMsg("message 1", "message 1 description", AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Warning );

//do lengthy stuff, simulated with a sleep here
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

//Update the form showing this message
alertMsg.ShowMsg("message 2", "message 2 description", AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Critical);

//do lengthy stuff, simulated with a sleep here
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

I already created the from 'AlertMsg' and this looks the way it should. It also shows the form when I call .ShowMsg the first time. Only the lables on the forms remain white. Also, when I call .ShowMsg the next time it does not update the form.

I think that to solve this I should create the form on a separate thread but I do not quite know how to do this. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

---

I tried the .Refresh tip that I got and now I have this. The above is still the calling program and this remains unchanged.

Now, in my class AlertMsg I have this (left some code out for the sake of brevity):

```
public class AlertMsg
{
    frmAlertMsg _frmAlertMsg;

    public AlertMsg()
    {
        _frmAlertMsg = new frmAlertMsg();
    }

    public void Show(string header, string text, MsgTypes msgType)
    {
        _frmAlertMsg.showMsg(header, text, msgType);  
    }
}
```

And in the form class I have this:

```
private void frmAlertMsg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - 420, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - 120);
}

internal void showMsg(string header, string text, AlertMsg.MsgTypes typeM )
{
    //left out setting the colors part here

    lblHeader.Text = header;
    lblDescription.Text = text;

    this.Show();
    this.Refresh();    
}
```

And this now perfectly displays the form with the labels set to the text that I give it. And it also updates when I call showMsg later again.

So thank you once again.

Comment: It sounds as though you're right that you need a separate thread. Start by googling "c# threading example", and try out a few of the things that are out there. If you run into a specific problem and can't resolve it, come back to SE and post a question with the problem code.

Comment: By the sake of curiosity, have you tried a simple ".Refresh()" on the control that does not display ? It worked for me in an almost similar situation.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Actually, first I simply tried the .Refresh tip and it works. Works like a charm actually!

Comment: Updated by code above to include the classes and reflect the changes that I made.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating the form in another thread, no.  You should have *one* UI thread for your application, not several.  If you have non-UI work you should offload that work to a non-UI thread.  Creating multiple UI threads is a real pain that you should avoid doing if at all possible.  Creating a new thread to do UI work while you do non-UI work in your UI thread is giving yourself way more work than you need.

Instead you need to write your program asynchronously.  You need to not block the UI thread for extensive periods of time and let it pump messages.

```
AlertMsg alertMsg = new AlertMsg();
alertMsg.ShowMsg("message 1", "message 1 description", 
    AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Warning);

await Task.Run(() => SomeLongRunningOperation());

alertMsg.ShowMsg("message 2", "message 2 description", 
    AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Critical);

await Task.Run(() => AnotherLongRunningOperation());
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution is to use Application.DoEvents() after painting on the form. However, putting your long running task to a seperate thread is definitely the right choice.

A threading example:

```
//Create the form here but do not show it yet
AlertMsg alertMsg = new AlertMsg();

//Show the form with this message
alertMsg.ShowMsg("message 1", "message 1 description", AlertMsg.MsgTypes.Warning );

ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                //do lengthy stuff, simulated with a sleep here
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
                if (alertMsg.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => alertMsg.Hide()));
                }
            });
Thread th = new Thread(ts);
th.Name = "longrunningtast";
th.Start();
```

Don't forget to use Invoke() if you have to write to the form from the new thread.

Comment: Creating a new thread is pointless if you're going to do nothing but wait for it to finish int he calling thread.

Comment: Thanks for this threading example. It may come in handy later. But for now I think I sufficiently solved it by using the .Refresh tip. But actually I cannot create a thread in the coding program because this will be in VBScript (in the actual case) and I am pretty sure that does not support threading. What I was thinking is to create the form that displays in a thread and create that thread in the constructor of the form class itself. But I am not sure if that is the right place.

Comment: @Servy If you want to send back status information for example and want your main thread and form to be responsive while running the long task this is a solution.

Comment: @Perrier No, this is not a solution.  You're blocking the main thread here, so it won't be responsive.

Comment: I compiled the dll as in my example above (so without any threading) and I call it from VBScript and it works just fine. So I think I'll leave it at this. Thanks for all the help on this!

Comment: @Servy I wrote in the comment that only one of the methods should be used just wanted to demonstrate some threading to help.

Comment: @Perrier And neither of your proposed solutions are good working solutions.  While it's certainly possible to use threads to solve this problem, the way that you showed how wouldn't work.